# Regex for matching words enclosed in some pattern (that can be dynamically added) and should also return words between enclosed matched words

Tags: regex

Let's have the sample string:

```
"Hello @{MATCH 1} My @[MATCH 2] Wonderful #{MATCH 3} World"
```

Assuming the following regexes were registered:

```
[/@\{.+\}/, /@\[.+\]/, /#\{.+\}/]
```

What I need is for the regex to return the following matches:

```
["Hello ", "@{MATCH 1}", " My ", "@[MATCH 2]", " Wonderful ", "#{MATCH 3}", " World"]
```

Currently what I do is compile the registered regexes by joining them with '|' and join a '.+?' pattern at the end. It will turn into something like:

```
/@\{.+\}|@\[.+\]|#\{.+\}|.+?/g
```

However this would return these matches:

```
["H", "e", "l", "l", ..., "@{MATCH 1}", " ", "M", ..., "@[MATCH 2]", ...]
```

I can live with the current matches, just need to perform extra processing with them. However, I am worried about the performance impact of such number of returned matches. Anyone knows a better regex for returning the matches that I desire? Please do note that the patterns **CAN BE DYNAMICALLY REGISTERED**. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
([@#]\{[^}]+\}|@\[[^\]]+\]|[^@#]+)
```

per this [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/JCRUZQhU7Y)

Update: Combined the two `{}` alternatives per @jkshah's helpful comment.

Comment: `@\{[^}]+\}` and `#\{[^}]+\}` can be combined as `[#@]\{[^}]+\}`